# How can i capture final value from text view in dismissed navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a navigation controller that has 2 view controllers in it.. viewController(A) and viewController(B).

In ViewController(A), I have code that defines the left and right navigation items for ViewController(B) and then pushes it onto the navigation stack.
That code, in the presenter, viewController(A), is shown here...

```
-(void)presentImageEditor
    {
        IGCellPath *pathForCurrentCell = [self pathForCurrentCell];
        iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:pathForCurrentCell.columnIndex];

        iRpImageEditorViewController *viewControllerB = [[iRpImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndMediaItem:imageAndMediaItem];

        viewControllerB.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
        viewControllerB.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
        viewControllerB.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imageEditorCancelled)];
        viewControllerB.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        [imageEditorNavController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
    }


-(void)imageEditorDone
    {
        [imageEditorNavController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [[iRpDatabase sharedInstance] saveChangesToDatabase];
    }


-(void)imageEditorCancelled
    {
        [imageEditorNavController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [[iRpDatabase sharedInstance] rollbackChangesToDatabase];
    }
```

The code in my presented view controller... viewController(B) has this...

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == descriptionView)
    {
        [theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj setValue:textView.text forKey:@"desc"];
    }
}
```

The problem is, that in the presented view controller, viewController(B), when they dismiss viewController(B), the `viewController(A) -(void)imageEditorDone` fires BEFORE the `viewController(B) -(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` method inside this presented view controller... viewController(B).  So I can't capture their last entry and save it before they dismiss the view controller, because the events are occuring in the wrong order.
I'd have expected that the view controller you're actually on would fire it's events `-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` before the presenting view controller fired its events `-(void)imageEditorDone`

How can I make sure I capture the last thing they did in a presented view before the presenters code fires to dismiss it?

Answer (score 1):

What about to swap these methods?

```
   [imageEditorNavController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [[iRpDatabase sharedInstance] saveChangesToDatabase];
```

Comment: The problem is further up the chain than that unfortunately...  the `imageEditorDone` method is called first, THEN the `textViewDidEndEditing` is called... so even swapping what you suggested won't capture the new text value early enough :(

Comment: Than add yout UIBarButtons inside of your vc with text and save your data inside its methods. -(void)imageEditorDone
    { [theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj setValue:self.textView.text forKey:@"desc"];
        [[iRpDatabase sharedInstance] saveChangesToDatabase];  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

Comment: I'll look into that option.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per a suggestion in a comment on Alex's post, this is what I did to make it work.  I attempted to edit his original answer (which was wrong) to his comment suggestion (which was right) in an attempt to give him the credit for the answer, but he rejected my edit, lolololool.

Instead of adding the bar button items from viewController(A) and the associated handlers in viewController(A), I added my bar button items (and associated handlers) in viewController(B), so that I can save the data in viewController(B) before it's dismissed.

So in viewController(B), in the init method perhaps, I did this...

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imageEditorCancelled)];
```

Then in your handlers, you could do something like this...

```
-(void)imageEditorDone
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    // Save your data here...

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(void)imageEditorCancelled
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```